# Clustering: a training dataset of variable data dimensions

Tags: cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset of n data, where each data is represented by a set of extracted features. Generally, the clustering algorithms need that all input data have the same dimensions (the same number of features), that is, the input data X is a n*d matrix of n data points each of which has d features.
In my case, I've previously extracted some features from my data but the number of extracted features for each data is most likely to be different (I mean, I have a dataset X where data points have not the same number of features).
Is there any way to adapt them, in order to cluster them using some common clustering algorithms requiring data to be of the same dimensions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the problem you have is that it's a 'sparse' data set. There are generally two options.

1. Reduce the dimensionality of the input data set using multi-dimensional scaling techniques. For example Sparse SVD (e.g. [Lanczos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm)) or [sparse PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_PCA). Then apply traditional clustering on the dense lower dimensional outputs.
2. Directly apply a sparse clustering algorithm, such as [sparse k-mean](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2930825/). Note you can probably find a PDF of this paper if you look hard enough online (try scholar.google.com).

*[Updated after problem clarification]*

In the problem, a handwritten word is analyzed visually for connected components (lines). For each component, a fixed number of multi-dimensional features is extracted. We need to cluster the words, each of which may have one or more connected components.

**Suggested solution:**

Classify the connected components first, into 1000(*) unique component classifications. Then classify the words against the classified components they contain (a sparse problem described above).

*Note, the exact number of component classifications you choose doesn't really matter as long as it's high enough as the MDS analysis will reduce them to the essential 'orthogonal' classifications.

Comment: The problem is that each data is an image containing one handwritten word. I always extract m fixed features from one connected component (a sort of pseudo-word) of the world, then if the word contain c connected components, the number of features extracted for this word is d=m*c. So, the number of features extracted for each data (word) of my dataset depends on c (the number of connected components that this word contain) and it could be different from one world to another (even for 2 words of the same class, but less often). In this case, is something like PCA helpful ? I'm not sure.

Comment: Are the features classified or continuous in nature? i.e. are there N possible features that a word can contain (in which case the word-feature matrix is sparse) or are the features essentially (fixed) multi-dimensional inputs themselves?, which the words may contain many of?

Comment: There are 70 possible features (continuous statistical values) that one letter can contain. Then, each data (a word containing "c" letters) is represented by 70*c values. Since "c" is different from one word to another, I will have a different number of values for different words.

Comment: Thanks. I've amended my answer to suggest you classify the connected components first using the 70 features, using traditional dense classification techniques, then you can classify the words against the  classified connected components they contain (a sparse problem).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, it seems to be a good idea. However, I don't see clearly how can I classify later the words against the classified connected components they contain. What the features vector of each word will contain ?

Comment: Say you classify the connected components into 1000 possible classifications. The features vector for each word is now a 1000 element array for each classification, containing either 1 or 0 depending on whether it contains that component classification (so actually that's a dense problem formulation as I've stated it).

Comment: Great I see better now thanks. So if I understand, to construct the features vector for each word I can process like following: Say I clustered all connected components thus I have a vector V of 1000 elements (each elem V[i] has 70 values); Now to construct the features vector V_w1 of the word w1 (say w1 has 3 components C1, C2, C3), I search for the V[i] that is nearest from C1 (using euclidean distance D(V[i], C1)) and I put 1 in the vector V_w1[i], I do the same thing for C2 and C3, and I put 0 in the other positions of the vector V_w1. I'll try this in the next few days and let you know.

Comment: Tim, if I have a sparse dataset where each data is described by a vector of 1000 elements, each element of this vector can be either 0 or 1 (a lot of 0 and some 1), do you know any distance function that could help me to cluster them ? I have not read the article yet ( the one that Tim gave me about sparse k-mean: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2930825/ ), but I would like to know first if there is a simple convenient distance metric for such a situation, to try on my data. @Anonymouse

Answer (score 1):

There are also clustering algorithms such as [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) that in fact do not care about your data. All this algorithm needs is a *distance function*. So if you can specify a distance function for your features, then you can use DBSCAN (or OPTICS, which is an extension of DBSCAN, that doesn't need the epsilon parameter).

So the key question here is **how you want to compare your features**. This doesn't have much to do with clustering, and is highly domain dependant. If your features are e.g. word occurrences, *Cosine distance* is a good choice (using 0s for non-present features). But if you e.g. have a set of SIFT keypoints extracted from a picture, there is no obvious way to relate the different features with each other efficiently, as there is no order to the features (so one could compare the first keypoint with the first keypoint etc.) A possible approach here is to derive another - uniform - set of features. Typically, **bag of words** features are used for such a situation. For images, this is also known as **visual words**. Essentially, you first cluster the sub-features to obtain a limited vocabulary. Then you can assign each of the original objects a "text" composed of these "words" and use a distance function such as cosine distance on them.

Comment: But the problem is the distance function itself. To specify a distance function (e.g. euclidean distance), you need that your vectors features have the same dimension.

Comment: Yes. You need to solve this first, before you can do any kind of clustering. How is a clustering algorithm supposed to group "similar" objects, when there is no way to compare them?
See the updated reply for some pointers (bag of words).

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1. Restrict yourself to those features for which all your data-points have a value.
2. See if you can generate sensible default values for missing features.

However, if possible, you should probably resample all your data-points, so that they all have values for all features.

Comment: Björn, I explain better my question: Each data of my dataset is an image containing one handwritten word. I always extract m fixed features from one connected component (a sort of pseudo-word) of the world, then if the word contain c connected components, the number of features extracted for this word is d=m*c. So, the number of features extracted for each data (word) of my dataset depends on c (the number of connected components that this word contain) and it could be different from one world to another. In this case, are the two options that you proposed applicable ?